# How to set the Local_C_INCLUDE in android.mk

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

when I use android studio to develop a JNI project, the `"opencv/core.hpp"` cannot be found. I know the reason is there is something wrong with `android.mk`. 
How can I rewrite the `Local_C_INCLUDE`

Comment: _How_ to add to it: `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += some/path`   _What_ to add to it: only you can know since the directory structure exists on your machine.

Comment: It might help if you showed the relevant parts of your android.mk file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link OpenCV libraries, you should add something like

```
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include D:/OpenCV-3.0.0/android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

in your **Android.mk** file. It will take care of your include paths, flags, and link libraries.